# Access Mercurial repo with Git on windows

Tags: python, windows, git, mercurial, msysgit

Since version 1.8.1 git is including Felipes [git-remote-hg](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) . Unfortunately fetching/cloning from a Hg repo with [TortoiseGit 1.8.1](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Download) and [Git for Windows 1.8.1.2](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe&can=2&q=full+installer+official+git) ends in the following error:

**fatal: git was built without support for git-core\git-remote-hg (NO_PYTHON=YesPlease).**

How do I get python support into my Git?

Comment: you could always use Kiln, they just released a new update.

Comment: What in my question indicated that I'm interested in a paid web-based solution?

Comment: Looks like Windows is the problem. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/msysgit/LpyViW97g0A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers none of the msys based git solutions for Windows have python support. Eventually they may have time to add it but who knows when that will happen.

In the meantime, git-remote-hg *does* work with Cygwin's git. Here's what I did to try it out:

1. Download the latest [Cygwin setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)
2. Run setup.exe and install latest git, mercurial, and openssl packages (in addition to whatever packages it wants to install). I installed mine in `c:\cygwin`.
3. Download [`git-remote-hg`](https://raw.github.com/git/git/v1.8.4.3/contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-hg) and put it in `c:\cygwin\bin`. (There may be a more appropriate place to put this file, but I didn't bother to figure out where that might be.)
4. I added `c:\cygwin\bin` to my PATH so I could use git commands from the Windows command prompt.

   It is worth noting that if you're using TortoiseHg or some other mercurial or python, putting `c:\cygwin\bin` in your path could cause those programs to misbehave. A more robust solution would be to make a `.cmd` file that modifies the PATH to include Cygwin's bin directory or just use Cygwin's bash shell.
5. Find some hg repo to clone. (I created one at `c:\hg\test` and used `hg serve`).
6. Clone with git:

   `git clone hg::http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: I fixed the link to git-remote-hg. It's coming from the https://github.com/git/git repo now and I have it from a tagged version so that link shouldn't change.

Comment: Thanks :). Although I ended up not being able to use it because there is no Windows version of Git that includes Python

Comment: That's what steps 1-2 are about. If you use cygwin for git, it will have python too.

Comment: There is no reason for a Git version on Windows requiring Python. I have msysGit installed, and git-remote-hg seems to with stock Python 2.7. Just make sure python.exe is in your path, so Bash can find it. It might work just as well with Git for Windows, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I came across this looking for a solution to the exact same error message while using git-p4. Simply installing cygwin git and using that instead seems to be sufficient for git-p4.